# Speeding up calculations on a table

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a table that will have different formulas for odd and even columns. I'm trying to loop through the table to do these calculations, but the problem is that it's taking forever, even when my code doesn't perform a calculation. Does anyone have suggestions on how I could improve my code? Here's what I've got so far:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim tCols As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim even As Boolean

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

With tbl.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count
    tCols = .Columns.Count
End With

'Start performing calculations
For i = 2 To tCols

    If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
        even = True
    Else
        even = False
    End If

    For i2 = 2 To tRows + 1
        If even Then
            'Formula for even columns
            Cells(i2, i) = "Even"
        Else
            'Formula for odd columns
            Cells(i2, i) = "Odd"
        End If
    Next i2

Next i
```

Comment: A simple addition would be to check if the current column would be odd or even. Making it a generic formula to be used in all columns, e.g.: `IF(ISODD(COLUMN()),"Use odd formula","Use even formula")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

Then run the following code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
tbl.DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()),TRUE,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

With the following result:

[image]

Note that:

- You must replace the `TRUE` part of my formula with your `ODD` formula.
- You must replace the `FALSE` part of my formula with your `EVEN` formula.
- I have used a explicit cell reference to `Sheet1` using it's `CodeName`. So change that accordingly

Regardless of amount of columns or rows, the whole `.DataBodyRange` has been filled according to the formula.

Comment: This is much more elegant! One issue is that I need the values in A2 through the last row in column A, and the name of the value of whatever's in the first row of that column. So my first formula is like this: =COUNTIFS(skill_title, A2, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 5), and that is for the even column. The odd is this calculation: =SUM(COUNTIFS(skill_title, A2, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 2), COUNTIFS(skill_title, A2, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 3), COUNTIFS(skill_title, A2, branch, $B$1, skill_prof, 4)).

Comment: Quick note: the "=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()),TRUE,FALSE)" works great, I just need to basically start the formulas in column 2, row 2, since I use the table header as a value and the value in column A.

Comment: I used this, and just used Range(tableRange).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISODD(COLUMN()), 3, 2)", where tableRange was a string of the portion of the table I wished to use. Thanks!